# Aptana Studio 3.4.2.2 Django not Found

Tags: django, aptana3

I am trying to set up a Django project in my stand alone Aptana Studio 3 but I get a "Django not found" error. I have it installed and have no problem with creating Django projects via command line using "django-admin.py startproject." What step am I missing?

Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805
Python 2.7.5
OSX 10.9

Comment: you probably have old installation of Mac Ports and Python that were interfering with the Aptana Studio.

Comment: I did double check my MacPorts. I ran port selfupdate and there are no outdated ports. I have to stay with Python version below 3 because of the project I am inheriting. Django will not work with Python 2.7 in Aptana Studio 3?

Comment: After a bit of hair pulling, I found that the "Auto Config" option in the Python Interpreter wasn't selecting the "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages" directory. After removing the old interpreter and re-configuring selecting that directory, all is well.